# Error while getting the redirected url in scrapy : Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using the code:

```
def parse_find(self, response):
    Download_URL = "https://download.example.com/b/zMTY"
    request = Request(Download_URL, callback=self.parse_final)

    yield request

def parse_final(self, response):
    redirected_URL = response.url

    FileName = response.headers['Content-Disposition']  

    yield{   "Download_URL":redirected_URL,
             "FileName":FileName}
```

to get the redirected url and its headers, but the scrapy gives debug:

```
2018-07-30 04:41:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (
302) to <GET https://example.com/url> from <GET https://download.example.com/b/zMTY>
2018-07-30 04:41:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (
meta refresh) to <GET https://example.com> from <GET https://example.com/url>
```

It must be noted that when I use fetch to extract this url in scrapy shell then it grabs the redirected url and response.headers works fine.

I'm using Python 3.6.5 and scrapy 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to do it with scrapy, I have done it via requests as :

```
    Down = requests.get(response.url,allow_redirects=False)
    if Down.status_code == 302:
        redirected_URL = Down.headers['location']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error - it's a `debug` log. Scrapy is informing you that redirect is happening for debuging purposes. You can change scrapy logs level with `LOG_LEVEL` setting. Outside of dev environment you should set it to `LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'`